# Program that determines if random number is divisible by user input

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, random, numbers

The user may only enter a number between 1 and 15, so if the input is out of 
range, output an error and ‘return’ out of the function. If the input is good, 
then proceed.

Create a loop that generates 10 random numbers between 1 and 100.

I know my javascript is incorrect, I'm stuck atm.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function loopNums() {

var usernum = parseInt( document.getElementById("usernum").value );
var msg = ""; // "" is the NULL string
var ;


for( var i = 1; i <= 15; i++ ) {

    if( i % usernum == 0) {

        msg = msg + "<div>" i + "is NOT divisible by " usernum + "</div>";

        msg = msg + "<div>You entered " + i + "</div>";
        sum = sum + i;

    } // ends the for loop

    msg = msg + "<div>The sum is " + sum + "</div>";

    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = msg;

} // end loopNums() function

</script>

<style type="text/css">

body {
background-color: #996666;
font-family: arial;
color: #996666;
}
#contentwrap {
background-color: #FFCC66;
border: 8px #FF9933 solid;
padding: 20px;
width: 600px;
margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
border-radius: 25px;
text-align: center;
}

#heading {
font-size: 2.2em;
border-bottom: 6px #663399 double;
padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

#formdiv {
text-align: center;
padding-top: 25px;
}

.formtext {
text-align: center;
font-size: 1.29em;
margin-top: 20px;
}

#usernum {
border: 2px #663399 solid;
}

#result {
font-size: 1em;
color: #FF0000;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="contentwrap">

<div id="heading">Loop Practice</div>

<div id="formdiv">

<form>

Enter a number<br />
<input type="text" id="usernum" /><p />

<input type="button" value="Go For It!" onClick="loopNums()" />

</form>

<div id="results"></div>

</div>

</div> <!-- ends div#contentwrap -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Paste the code into your question.  Fiddle links are for demonstrations, not code archiving.

Comment: Open your console, you'll find an error message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [YOUR UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v9WpC/5/):

```
function loopNums() {
    var usernum = parseInt(document.getElementById("usernum").value);
    var msg = ""; // "" is the NULL string
    var sum = 0;

    if (usernum < 1 || usernum > 15) {
        msg = "Enter a number between 1 and 15";
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var rdnNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * ( 1 + 100 - usernum )) + usernum;

            if (rdnNumber % usernum === 0)
                msg += "<div style='color: green'>Number generated: " + rdnNumber + ". It is divisible by " + usernum + "!</div>";
            else
                msg += "<div style='color: red'>Number generated: " + rdnNumber + ". It is not divisible by " + usernum + "!</div>";
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = msg;
}
```

Comment: I find it remarkable that you figured this out so fast. I personally thought this assignment was very difficult, even after doing a few other loop assignments in class. I even looked at the codes for help and comparison, but I was getting nowhere.

Comment: Question. When you increment i, how come you set the 2nd statement to <10?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question.

Comment: for( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {  How did you know to use i < 10 for the second statement>? Is that correct?

Comment: You said: "Create a loop that generates 10 random numbers between 1 and 100". If you need to generate 10 random numbers, you need to make 10 iterations. Sorry, I still can't figure out what you're asking.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. You answered my question. Thanks.